# Data Binding Property fire PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I've a View (UserControl) with two user controls on it:

- first UC is a search control
- second UC is a detail control

When I select a DataGrid row in the search control, I bind this selected Item to the detail control - this all works fine.

I have a ViewModel which is bound to the View (as DataContext).

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Interface for PropertyChanged is implemented, I will not post this code here ...

    // This should be set, when any textbox/control is changed in the detail
    public boolean DataChanged { get; set; }

    private User _user;
    public User Data {
        get { return this._user; }
        set
        {
            if(value != _user) {                
               this._user = value;
               this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Data");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the view, the detail control is defined like this

```
<local:UserDetailControl 
        x:Name="userDetailControl"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</local:UserDetailControl>
```

The DataContext Binding for the detail control is set to the ViewModel's `Data` Property. 
This works fine, the text boxes will be filled with the correct data.

Example for Control in Detail UC:

```
<TextBox x:Name="idTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What I want to have is following: If any control (textbox) is changed in the detail UC, the ViewModel Property `DataChanged` should be changed (to true).

I tried following ...

1) Added `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the detail user control, added a Property for `ID`, but setter/getter will not be called because Binding object is the DataContext.

2) Added a DependencyProperty for `ID` and raise PropertyChanged

```
public string ID
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(IDProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IDProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(string), typeof(UserDetailControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnIDChanged));

private static void OnIDChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UserDetailControl control = obj as UserDetailControl;
    control.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
}
```

But this will never be called ...

3) Adding a TextChanged event for (every) textbox and raise the PropertyChanged event. (this works, but is not elegant I think)

4) I am thinking about to bind the DataChanged Property to the detail UC, but this will not fix my problem ... it would just be a nicer way where i could handle the state in the detail UC.

---

So, are the any other ideas/solutions/suggestions how i can fix my problem in an easy way? Thank you, guys!

---

### Update / Solution

Added a new Dependency Property `Data` to Detail UserControl and set the TextBox Property to this `Data.ID`.

```
    public User Data
    {
        get
        {
            return (User)GetValue(DataProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(User), typeof(UserDetailControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDataChanged));


    private static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        UserDetailControl control = obj as UserDetailControl;
        control.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
    }
```

Then I had to modify my Detail UC XAML Code:

```
 <UserControl ... x:Name="root">
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-193" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
 </UserControl>
```

(see: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html)

Comment: I found a solution => see update above

Comment: good................